# BitConverter is using Big when it should use little endian

Tags: c#, byte

I have a file I'm reading two bytes from. (03, 0E). I use the binary reader to get my bytes

```
 reader.ReadBytes( 2 ), 0 )//[0] = 03  and [1] = 0E
```

then I convert with

```
 BitConverter.ToInt16( reader.ReadBytes( 2 ), 0 )
```

the convert has little endian set to true, so correct me if I'm wrong but that means 0x03 then 0x0E and my result should be 782 in decimal but its showing as 3587. I checked the immediate window and its the converter that is swapping. I'm missing something here certainly but I don't know what?

Comment: Are you _actually_ reading from the reader twice or just showing the two versions for testing purposes?

Comment: sorry I was doing that for illustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it backwards.  From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx):

> "Big-endian" means the most significant byte is on the left end of a word. "Little-endian" means the most significant byte is on the right end of a word.

So reading `{03},{0E}` in a little-endian system means that `0E` is the *most significant* byte, so when read into a 2-byte structure it represents `0E03` in hex, or 3,587 in decimal.

Comment: Please accept this answer if you agree with it, so people like me will not spend time opening this question ;)

Comment: well its not fully answered yet actually?  According to the docs for BinaryReader "BinaryReader reads this data type in little-endian format." As you can see from my first post its reading Big Endian, so I'm still confused why its not reading the right way.

Comment: But you're not reading `int16`s, you're reading `byte`s.  So it will read the bytes in the order they come from the stream.  If the source data is big-endian than you will need to reverse the bytes before converting to a different data type.